# In JAWS while closing the accordion jaws focus is going to next item

Tags: html, css, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

JAWS and chrome> while collapsing the element, the focus is being shifted to the next element instead of having it on the same element.
Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. tab to first element and activate it with the enter key
2. once it expands, go through the details with the arrow keys
3. press shift tab to reach to the first expanded element  and press enter
   key to collapse it
4. element gets collapsed but you would observe that jaws focus is being
   shifted to the next element. Instead, jaws focus should remain on the
   first element itself

```css
summary {
     display: block;
     background: black;
     color: white;
     padding: 1rem;
    }

    details {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    details p {
     margin: 1rem auto;
     translate: 2rem 0;
    }

    summary > * {
     display: inline;
    }
```

```html
 <details>
  <p>Answer!</p>
  <summary>
   <h3>Question?</h3>
  </summary>
 </details>
 <details>
  <p>Answer!</p>
  <summary>
   <h3>Question?</h3>
  </summary>
 </details>
 <details>
  <p>Answer!</p>
  <summary>
   <h3>Question?</h3>
  </summary>
 </details>
```

Comment: I didn't check if it's the cause of the problem, but is there a particular reason why your `<summary>` element is after detail content, rather than before ? To me it looks completely illogical.

Comment: Also, an advice for question askers in general: please post your code after your actual question rather than before, so that the first words of your question can appear in the question list, rather than the beginning of your code. This helps, along with the question title, before actually opening it, if it's worth it  to do so (if I may know the answer or obviously not). Thank you.

Comment: @QuentinC Thanks for the suggestion. In general can you check any other accordion examples when we close the accordion the jaws focus is getting shifted to the next one. For now can you consider this URL once https://www.aditus.io/patterns/accordion/

Comment: I just tried with JAWS on Chrome and when I tabbed backwards to the first accordion and collapsed it, my JAWS focus stayed on the first accordion.

Comment: It would seem weird that this is related to JAWS. You’re probably on Chrome? Can you reproduce the issue without JAWS?

Comment: In fact I just made a small test right now with Jaws 2022 and latest Chrome, and the focus is correct, both with your code and on the live demo given as link. Can you tell us with which version of Jaws and which browser do you observe that ?

Comment: @Andy I tried without JAWS it is fine